# PHP IP detection in search script

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP script that detects the users IP address and displays it when they search for a certain term in a search script. When the user searches for something with the words "what is my ip" in it, their IP is displayed. My question is; how can I do the same thing if the user was to search "what's my ip address" or searches with upper case letters?

I hope you can understand my question. Here is my PHP code:

```
if(strpos($_GET['q'],'what is my ip')===0){
    echo "Your IP address is <b>{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}</b><br><a href='http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address'>What is an IP address?</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to make the case matter, use the `strpos` variant that ignores case (case- *i*nsensitive) [`stripos`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php):

```
if(stripos($_GET['q'],'what is my ip')===0){
      ^
```

Answer (score 0):

for the uppercase part - just convert the query string to lower or uppercase. that gives you control over the string.